# uploading file details in html table

Tags: javascript, html

While uploading multiple files, i want to show the details of the multiple files selected in the html table once user has selected the files to upload. Issue is i should not use "File API" as it is not supported in IE8. Please find the same in "http://jsfiddle.net/KQQCQ/1/".
Below is the JavaScript code:

```
var fileNameIndex = document.getElementById('fileUpload').value.lastIndexOf("\\");
    var file_name = document.getElementById('fileUpload').value.substring(fileNameIndex + 1);

    if(document.getElementById("sno1").value == ''){
    document.getElementById("sno1").value=rowN;
    document.getElementById("fileName1").value=file_name;
    rowN++;
    } else{
            document.getElementById("sno2").value=rowN;
            document.getElementById("fileName2").value=file_name;
        }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="uploadFile_div"><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" id="fileUpload" multiple/></div> 

<table border="1" id="uploadTable" style="visibility:hidden;" align="center">

           <tr> <th width="50px" style="text-align: center;">SNo</th><th width="100px" style="text-align: center;">FileName</th><th width="100px" style="text-align: center;">Action</th> </tr>
          <tr><td width="50px"><input type="text" name="sno1" id="sno1"/></td>
             <td width="100px"><input type="text" name="fileName1" id="fileName1" border="0"/></td> 

           </tr>  

            <tr><td><input type="text" name="sno2" id="sno2"/></td>
             <td width="100px"><input type="text" name="fileName2" id="fileName2"/></td> 

           </tr>     
</table>
```

Please suggest, how to show the details of multiple files selected by the user in the html table and other issue which i noticed is in IE8 i'm unable to select multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last part of your question first, IE8 and IE9 do not support multiple file selection and upload.

As for listing the files in the table, this code ought to work...

Javscript:
        var _validFileExtensions = [".xls",".xslx",".pptx", ".ppt", ".doc", ".docx", ".txt"];

```
    var validateFileUpload = function () {
        document.getElementById("uploadTable").style.visibility="visible";

        var filelist = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files || [];
        console.log(filelist);
        for (var i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
            var file_name = filelist[i].name;       

            if (isValid(file_name)) {
                var table = document.getElementById("uploadTable"),
                    row = document.createElement("tr"),
                    col1 = document.createElement("td"),
                    col2 = document.createElement("td");

                col1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i+1));
                col2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file_name));
                row.appendChild(col1);
                row.appendChild(col2);
                table.appendChild(row);
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, " + file_name + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
            }
        }      
    }

    function isValid(file_name) {
        var blnValid = false;
        if (file_name.length > 0) {
          for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
              var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
              if (file_name.substr(file_name.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                  blnValid = true;
                  break;
              }
           }
        }
        return blnValid;
    }

    document.getElementById("fileUpload").onchange = validateFileUpload;
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="uploadFile_div"><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" id="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" /></div>
    <table border="1" id="uploadTable" style="visibility:hidden;" align="center"></table>
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/9GsNf/1/